# Как получить Access Token юзера с facebook, используя библиотеку facebook4j?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-api, web-apps, token

Меня интересует как получить `Access Token` через `Facebook` используя библиотеку `facebook4j`?

И в целом, как аутентифицировать юзера через `Facebook` используя `facebook4j`.

---

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
         .setOAuthAppId(APP_ID)
         .setOAuthAppSecret(APP_SECRET)
         .setOAuthAccessToken(USER_ACCESS_TOKEN)
         .setOAuthPermissions(SCOPE)
         .setUseSSL(true)
         .setJSONStoreEnabled(true);
 FacebookFactory ff = new FacebookFactory(cb.build());
 Facebook facebook = ff.getInstance();
```